# low pass filter class d amplifier

Tags: class-d

I am designing a Class D audio amplifier. Im using a 40Khz triangular wave to modulate my input audio signal of 1Khz. However when I designed my low pass filter(cut-off frequency=20Khz), I still get the triangular wave frequency at the output. this shows my LPF isnt working. Is there any reason why this could be happening. My final schematic is shown below.

Thank you

Output of LPF after changing freq. to 300KHz. Why is the output like that?

Comment: What is your question? I don't see a single question mark.

Comment: Is there any reason why this could be happening?

Comment: Nowadays ICs are so common.

Comment: Kelvin-Hertz is not a meaning measure of anything related to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Your low pass filter frequency is 28.2 kHz as per this formula: -

F = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$ where L is 22.5 uH and C is 1.41 uF

Your PWM frequency is 40 kHz and hence the filter attenuation will only be a few decibels and you will see on your output that the PWM signal has turned into a still-significant triangle wave. Here's what the frequency response might look like for a reasonably optimumly designed LC low pass filter at 28 kHz: -

[image]

There are three coloured vertical lines. The orange one is at 20 kHz, the green one is at 28 kHz (the 3 dB frequency) and the purple one is at 40 kHz. You should be able to see that the PWM signal is probably only attenuated by about 12 dB compared to the flat line in the passband. 12 dB is about a 4:1 attenuation and the squareness of the PWM starts to look like a triangle wave due to the way the harmonics are progressively filtered.

You need to be looking at something like 280 kHz to obtain an attenuation of about 40 dB (real numbers = 100:1 reduction).

Comment: I tried a frequency of 300KHz and simulated it using only the inductor and capacitor. I applied a square wave using a signal generator (at 1KHz). The Frequencies above 20Khz was attenuated. However when I applied this to the class d circuit I was not getting the sine wave ouput. I got an exponentially increasing graph that settled to an horizontal line. WHat could be the reason for this?

Comment: I have no idea what experiment you are describing to me. This means I cannot answer your comment. Re-word and simplify. I don't understand the "exponentially increasing graph that settled to an horizontal line" - this sounds contradictory let alone what you are describing. Do you see my problem?

Comment: The graph obtained is shown above, sorry for the vague description

Comment: I have no idea what it shows or what you would like it to show. If I were you I'd raise a new question about your basic design and whether it can hack 300 kHz PWM. Going from 40 kHz switching to nearly ten times that amount WILL create issues that need solving undoubtedly. Take up the frequency bit by bit until you see the onset of what problem it is that you see and look at other waveforms to get an idea what it is but I have no idea what the symptom is (let alone the problem) based on what you have told me.

Answer (score 2):

A LP filter 2. order only decreases the amplitude by 12dB per octave - so your triangle with double the cut-off frequency will still have an amplitude of -15dB. I would choose a way higher modulator frequency to fix this.

Comment: Well, it does not have to be that high, but maybe try something like 250kHz. You can calculated quite easy how much amplitude will be left at a given frequency. Then you can determine if that is sufficient for you or not.

Comment: I increased the frequency to 300Khz. I simulated it by just using an inductor and capacitor. I found that frequnecies above the cutt-off frequency was attenuated. However when I applied this to the output of the Class D amp, I wasnt getting the correct sine output. What could be the issue? (The output increased exponentially for a bit then started to straighten horizontally)